# Passing data through a hyperlink WITHOUT include the data in the URL

Tags: php, javascript

I know how to pass data through a URL and how to receive the data using `$_GET` but I don't want the variables to show up in the URL.

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail, citing specific code where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data via form POST or [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php), but you may want to provide more detail so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use JavaScript to override the normal functionality of the link and issue a POST request (e.g. with XHR).

Don't do that though. If you want a POST request, use a `<form>` with a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your only alternative is to submit a POST request against the URL.

- [Differences between GET & POST](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_get_and_post_method_in_HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  $_POST if you want to use data in next page only or $_SESSION if you want data through out the website.

for post you need to specify methood = post in form tag..

and to define session you need to use,

$*SESSION['var* name'] = $var_val;

Answer (score 0):

you can set a cookie both can read. or put the data in the header.